# Repeater Control with Paging: How to freeze Page? avoiding unnecessary hit to session again

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, repeater

I'm using Repeater Control with Paging. For the first 100 records i'm displaying 1, 2, 3, 4, "Next" links i.e., 25 records for each page.

On click of "Next" link, i'll fetch next 100 records from database. the same way when i click on "Prev" link. I achieved all this functionality.

Now, i need to avoid unnecessary hit to session if i click on the same page.

For example: consider i'm on 2nd page, if i click on Page "2" link again, i don't want hit the session again. How to achieve this in a simpler way.

I'm using C#, Javascript Pagemethods..

Thanks is Advance.

Comment: Using your example, just make "2" not-clickable.

Comment: How to make an anchor unclickable? and after clicking the other link make the clicked one unclickable and the other links clickable.. could you please provide me some code to signify what you said? 

Thanks..

Comment: Without seeing your code, I cannot provide any sample code. If you would like to update your answer with your **Paging** code, I would be more than happy to help out. That being said, are you rolling your own paging code? IF you are, you can simply output the current page as text, rather than a link.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?